# Why is onSaveInstanceState called when starting new activity?

Tags: android

Why is `onSaveInstanceState` called when starting new activity with `startActivity(intent)`, but when user presses back or home from new activity, `onRestoreInstanceState` is not called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate from Activity A to Activity B, Activity A will have its `onSaveInstanceState()` method invoked **in case** Activity A is destroyed (because the system needs to free up resources).

When you navigate back from Activity B to Activity A, there are a few different paths the code can take. If Activity A is still up and running, it will simply resume (and you'll see `onResume()` called). If instead Activity A was destroyed by the system while you were on Activity B, Activity A will need to be recreated. You'll see `onCreate()` called by the system (and its param `savedInstanceState` will be non-null and populated with what you put into it in `onSaveInstanceState()`) as well as any other lifecycle methods that happen "after" onCreate().

Comment: So if activity A is destroyed and `onCreate` is called then shouldn't `onRestoreInstanceState` be called?

Comment: If the activity was destroyed (so `onCreate()` is called _with a non-null savedInstanceState_) then yes, I'd expect `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` to be called as well (note that this is not the same as `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle, PersistableBundle)`, which won't usually be called).

Comment: Then, what's the solution if I want to save certain data in Activity A and get it without requesting it again when I back from activity B.